# Can we use Azure SSIS IR runtime to move data from on-premise to Azure Sql Database?

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure. I have a requirement to move data from on-premise to Azure SQL database. However, I have to use/execute the existing SSIS packages on Azure. I am thinking of using SSIS IR for executing SSIS packages. With this IR, is it also possible to move data from on-premise to Cloud or do I need a self hosted IR as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it also possible to move data from on-premise to Cloud

Yes but you need to join the SSIS-IR to  a VNET which in turn has connectivity to on prem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/join-azure-ssis-integration-runtime-virtual-network

VNET connectivity to on prem is achieved with a VPN or Express link from on prem to your VNET. There are varying degrees of complexity.

If you are going to undertake a lot of hybrid network projects (on prem joined to Azure) you should begin provisioning a VPN or Express route now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime)：

**Self-hosted IR:**
You can connect to the on-premise SQL Server via Self-hosted IR in Azure Data Factory. You can set up a Copy activity in ADF to copy data from on-premise db to Azure SQL.

- You will need to install Self-hosted IR on an on-premises machine or a virtual machine inside a private network.
- It has high availability and scalability, you can install Self-hosted IR on multiple compute nodes and form a group.

**Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime:**
To lift and shift existing SSIS workload, you can create an Azure-SSIS IR to natively execute SSIS packages.
You need to do:

- [Deploy SSIS packages to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).
- Create an Azure-SSIS integration runtime in data factory.

**Pricing:**

- [Self-hosted integration runtime princing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/).
- [SQL Server Integration Services Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/ssis/)

After comparing prices, we can see SSIS IR is more expensive than Self-hosted IR.

**Conclusion:**
I suggest you to use Self-hosted IR directly, it is simpler, more convenient and cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to execute SSIS packages on cloud only using the self hosted IR?

Comment: If you want execute SSIS packages, you must use Azure-SSIS IR. Self hosted IR only support to set up connectors to local SQL Server.